# What is the best practice when updating a progress bar?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I am currently working on a project in ASP.NET MVC 4 and came along a module where a progress bar is needed. The question I am having right now is "What is the best way to implement an async progress bar?".

After some lookup I came across the following method:

1. Create a startEvent() and getProgress() in C# code.
2. Use javascript setTimeout() to call the getProgress() method asynchronously.

(Example: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E4244)

My remark with this method is that that causes the code to be dependent on the timeout you choose. So it would take some fiddling to find the best and most performant timeout.

Now the method that I would most likely have used before I researched the matter is the following:

1. In code behind, create a method handleItem(int index) which takes an index and does everything you want to do with the item at that index.
2. Determine the number of items you want to handle and pass that to your javascript.
3. In javascript, initiate a for loop that loops from 0 to the amount - 1, and for each index, it initiates an ajax-call to handleItem(i).
4. On that ajax-call's complete-statement, you can update the progress bar with the new amount.

My questions here are the following:

1. Does this expose too much of the program logic?
2. Does this create too much overhead seeing as every call goes to the server and back?
3. Are there any other reasons why I should refrain from using this method?

Thanks in advance
Koen Morren

Answer (score 0):

This is not a recommended strategy, because the client drives the process. If there is any discontinuation of connectivity or maybe the user closes the browser, the process will stop.

Generally, if you use straight HTTP you will need to poll (aka pull) from javascript. The pseudo code is pretty much this:

```
Call Creates Task ID and sends it to client
Client queries the status of task with given ID
```

Another possibility are [WebSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket), which allow your client to listen for changes that are pushed by the server.

There are many options to store the progress of a given state. You can index the progress by the `HttpContext`, task id, or some user id, or even store it in a database and use `SqlDependency` to get notifications of when the status is changed.

In summary, polling has more lag than push mechanisms. Clients should not drive an asynchronous process, but they should be either notified or provided some mechanisms on the status of an async process.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike ASP.NET, there is few way to push data from server to client in MVC, WebSockets or [SingnalR](http://signalr.net/) like api(s) can work for you.

The ajax approach is good and give you reliable mechanism to update data no matter user go to other page or closes the browser, every time ajax launched it will update UI. So there is nothing wrong there just have a fair interval in javascript.

1. Does this expose too much of the program logic?

   Code will be written only in class file to calculate current %age.

2.Does this create too much overhead seeing as every call goes to the server and back?

No, ajax are light-weight calls

3.Are there any other reasons why I should refrain from using this method?

This method will allow user to freely navigate to other resources as ajax will work independently.